# ionic How to store the data of ion-range into firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I am trying to use ion-range to store its data to firebase but I cannot figure out how to do it.

my ion-range has 5 options and I used formControlName but I got error

```
<ion-toolbar>
        <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>Choose one</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col float-left>
            none
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2 class="colLeft">
              <p class="colLeft25">1</p>
            </ion-col>
          <ion-col ion-item no-lines text-center col-2 >
            2-3
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2 class="colRight">
            <p class="colRight22">4</p>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2  class="colRight">
            5+
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-range min="1" max="5" step="1" snaps="true">
        </ion-range>
      </ion-toolbar>
```

in .ts file, and .html file, what can I use to save its data?

Comment: what error did you get and how are you saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to save data into my Database.
I have used ngModel:

```
<ion-range min="1" max="5" step="1" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="profile.number">
```

and some backend job in my .ts file